# Wondering what is dropped timestams in sstablemetadata output in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

The Datastax docs [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsSSTableMetadata.html) say:

> The sstablemetadata utility prints metadata about a specified SSTable. The utility displays metadata that includes:
>
> ...
>
> number of tombstones and Dropped timestamps (in epoch time)

So I was wondering what does this value mean?

Comment: Can you link to the docs in your original question please?

Comment: I have added the link.

Answer (score 1):

So this value simply means the number of tombstones that are written at that timestamp for example:

```
Estimated tombstone drop times:
1524999800: 1456700
```

Would mean that there are `1456700` records deleted on `Sun 29 Apr 2018 12:03:20 BST`